# Android cache data and update strategy?

Tags: android, caching, service, background

I'll be fetching news and weather data from different sources.

And to cache I'm thinking of storing json string, with key value pair in SQLite along with the time stamp when the first data was fetched from server.

If data is more than one hour old, then check for updates, else use the existing data to load into objects and display.

Is this OK ?

And how can I run an hourly check ? One way is to check each time a user is using the app, but is there any other way like using some kind of background services ?

NOTE:
This question might have been asked, but a few that I searched was not what I am thinking.

Comment: I'm assuming this is remote content? Why not just use the built-in HTTP response caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a Scheduling Repeating Alarm, please read the following link:

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set

Example code:

```
private void scheduleService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
    long ONE_HOUR_RETRY_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60*60*1000;

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ONE_HOUR_RETRY_TIME, pintent);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is nice. So this way i can also put some local notifications to let user know about the updates? But what do you say for the caching strategy ?

Comment: Yes, you could easily add notifications and I think that your caching strategy is ok, JSON parsing could be costly, but you are only doing it hourly. It would be an inneficient strategy though, if users could check for updates at anytime.